# Is is possible to use Font Awesome icons in Mapbox Markers?

Tags: icons, marker, mapbox

I'm using the Maki set of icons, but they are very limited and would like to be able to use Font Awesome icons.  Is this possible?

Here's the code I'm using to set up the marker icons.

```
marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
    'title': jobid,
    'marker-color': '#e32f2f',
    'marker-symbol': 'square'
}));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've included the font awesome CSS on your page, you can use the `L.DivIcon` constructor to create custom icon.

```
<style>
/*
 * Unlike other icons, you can style `L.divIcon` instances with CSS.
 * These styles make each marker a circle with a border and centered
 * text
 */
.fa-icon {color: red;}
</style>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio')
    .setView([45.52245801087795, -122.67773866653444], 3);

L.marker([45.52245801087795, -122.67773866653444], {
    icon: L.divIcon({
        // specify a class name that we can refer to in styles, as we
        // do above.
        className: 'fa-icon',
        // html here defines what goes in the div created for each marker
        html: '<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i>',
        // and the marker width and height
        iconSize: [40, 40]
    })
}).addTo(map);
```

Here's a full example: http://jsbin.com/tiyote/1/

Comment: This method is easily generalized to non fa icons. +1

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.  Based on your example I was able to update my original code to use L.divIcon instead of L.mapbox.marker.icon.

```
marker.setIcon(L.divIcon({
    className: 'count-icon-emergency',
    html: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>',
    iconSize: [40, 40]
}));
```